# Reverse a singly-Linked List without changing the orginal LinkedList

Tags: python, algorithm, singly-linked-list

I've have two `.py` files.

1. `LinkedList.py` which holds a custom-built `Node` class.
2. `script.py` which contains my code to reverse the `LinkedList`

I'm importing the Node class like so in the `script.py`: 
`from LinkedList import *`
I've made a function named `reverse_linked_list` in `script.py` which holds a parameter named `linked_list`.

I'm able to reverse the linked_list like so:

```
def reverse_linked_list(linked_list):
  prev = None
  current = Node(linked_list).data
  while (current is not None):
    nextNode = current.next
    current.next = prev
    prev = current
    current = nextNode
  current = prev
  return prev
```

I've been handed some objects to work with

```
print("Original")
demo_list = make_linked_list([4,8,15])
demo_list.print_linked_list()
print("Reversed")
reverse = reverse_linked_list(demo_list)
reverse.print_linked_list()
print("Original Unchanged")
demo_list.print_linked_list()
```

The implementation of the Node class look like this:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next_node
```

I'm trying to understand why my code is changing the "original list" but can't figure out why.
The output I'm getting is:

```
Original
4
8
15
Reversed
15
8
4
Original Unchanged
4
```

I want that "Original Unchanged" dont get changed and stay as "Original".
where does the original list getting changed and why?

Comment: Please show the implementation of your Node class

Comment: For this to happen you need to create new nodes.

Comment: @ArthurKing I´ve updated the question. thats the implementation of the Node class I´ve got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the functions/methods that will make the driver code work as expected:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self
        while node:
            yield node.data
            node = node.next

    def __repr__(self):
        return "->".join(map(repr, self))
    
    def print_linked_list(self):
        print(self)


def reverse_linked_list(iterable):
    revhead = None
    for data in iterable:
        revhead = Node(data, revhead)
    return revhead

def make_linked_list(values):
    return reverse_linked_list(reversed(values))
```

Note that `reverse_linked_list` is able to create a linked list from not only another linked list, but any iterable. This is because a `Node` instance is made iterable by implementing the `__iter__` method.

Here is your driver code, with the output it will generate:

```
print("Original")
demo_list = make_linked_list([4,8,15])
demo_list.print_linked_list()
print("Reversed")
reverse = reverse_linked_list(demo_list)
reverse.print_linked_list()
print("Original Unchanged")
demo_list.print_linked_list()
```

Output:

```
Original
4->8->15
Reversed
15->8->4
Original Unchanged
4->8->15
```

Comment: Great! I forgot allbout `__iter__`, I learned alot of the explanation aswell! Thank you. I tried to make a itreble with `iter()` but I could not make it work, what is the diffrance between `iter()` and `__iter__`

Comment: `iter()` is a function (not a method) that you use to get an iterator from a given object that must have implemented (or inherited) an `__iter__` method. But when you do `for .. in`, you don't need to call `iter()`. Usually you only need to call `iter()` when you also want to use `next()` on the iterator object you get. All this is not needed with `for..in` constructs.